# Top Menu (Nav Bar) Not Showing on RWD Template

Tags: magento-1.9, navigation, menu

I have downloaded Magento 1.9 from the 1&1 App Center. It's a fresh install that is using the RWD template by default. I am new to Magento but have some web design experience.

My issue is that the top menu is not showing and has never shown. Is it disabled by default? I have one category with one item that I'm testing the store with, but how do I enable the top menu? [http://camilouscloset.com/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIRQr.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you set `Include in Navigation Menu` to Yes ?

Answer (score 1):

Please compare your setting with the one in the attached snap.
Navigate to **Catalog->Manage Categories**.
[image]

Comment: Yes, I have set Is Active and Include in Navigation Menu to yes. But no menu shows on the site. I will edit my post to include screenshots.

Comment: is your category is under Default Category

Comment: Make sure to set "Is Anchor" to Yes on the Display Settings tab

Comment: Ok for both categories, the default: CamiLous Closet, and the second: Wallets, I have changed the Is Anchor from No to Yes, and flushed the Magento cache. I refreshed the frontend home page and still no top menu / nav bar.

Comment: ok lets have a try rename rwd directory situated under **app\design\frontend**  and clear var directory after which you will be shifted to default theme of magento. check whether it is visible there or not. if it is visible then it might be css or js issue of rwd theme .

Comment: OK, so that reset the theme as expected but there is still no top menu showing. Would it be possible to give you access, so you can investigate yourself?

Comment: yes it is possible but not right now give me at 10 PM

Answer (score 1):

You should check below settings:

**Catalog->Manage Categories**

[image]

**System > Manage Store > Edit Store**

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have that set. Please see added screenshot. I can't add the screenshot because I don't have enough rep to post three links, but rest assured that the Store Information section is set correctly.

Comment: Have you installed any plugin related to navigation ? Try to chek by disabling them one bye one

Comment: I have not installed any plugins or extras. This is a new install working from the default template and settings. I didn't even choose the RWD template, that's the one that came as the default